# how do i calculate the average of 12 test scores using a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

its getting the sum correct but not the average. any help would be great.

```
sum=0

for i in range(12):
    score_i=int(input('What is the score of exam %s: ' %(i+1)))
    sum=sum+score_i

avg=sum/12

print(avg)
```

Comment: What Python version is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding a decimal point `avg=sum/12.`

Comment: In Python 3 (which this presumably is), `/` performs standard division, not integer division.

Comment: @arshajii I wasn't making that presumption

Comment: Well I think the fact that the OP is using the `print` function as opposed to the statement is a good indication. Also, he's not using `xrange()` *and* he's not using `raw_input`. But you're right, we can't be certain.

Answer (score 1):

First off, `sum` is a built-in function in Python. You shouldn't be using that as a variable.

With `avg=sum/12` you are dividing an integer by an integer, which floors the answer in Python 2.

`avg = sum/12.0` should produce the desired result.